# Incorrect order with ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ActiveRecord with PostgreSql and I am using the order method.

But the order is incorrect.

in the categories_controller

```
def show
    @categories = Category.all.order('id DESC')
end
```

in the categories show view

```
<% @category.posts.each do |post| %>
<p><%= post.id %></p>
<% end %>
```

It shows the order like this.

```
  <p>3</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
```

Comment: In `show` method, you've defined `@categories`, but in the view you're using `@category`. Also, you're sorting out the `Category` model, but in the view, you're showing a category's posts. That's completely unrelated.

Comment: You want to order on `category` or `posts`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to order by `post.id` but you are actually ordering by `category.id`. The correct query would be:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@category.posts.order(:id).each do |post|
  post.id
end
```